# how to include a php header in html

Tags: php, html

I am including the footer content using this code

```
 <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

It happens that I also have html files.
How can I also include the footer in my html files?

Comment: just save as you .html file to .php

Comment: @dev odedra. What if the files have to explicitly be html?

Comment: Then you can't include the file.

Comment: The other option I thought about,is to duplicate the footer.php and change the extension to htm. How can I carry from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, in order to include PHP files in your other files, all files need to be in the PHP extension.

In most cases, just renaming your HTML files to `.php` will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native include in HTML. Do these other files need to be HTML? If not you could change them to PHP which still lets you use any HTML code plus the PHP include.

Comment: Unfortunately they have to be html. Is there a way around?

Comment: If you do not care about having the footer as a public file you could include it using JavaScript. See: [W3Schools - How To Include HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: How would it work if  I change the footer extension to htm (footer.htm)?

Comment: That should not make a difference. Have you tried W3Schools' HTML includes? In their TryIt-Editor I was able to successfully include a .asp file using their JavaScript code. I am sure it should work for any extension.

Comment: @ kalsowerus.I am using this snippet from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_2 but for some reason it pulls  the footer twice.
Had a problem with the Internet but hopefully I don't have it again soon.

Comment: Remember that the TryIt-Editor does not save any of your changes, we only see the basic example behind that link. But using Google Chrome I checked the Requests generated by the script. It only pulled each of the includes once for me, just as intended.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't think of that. Weird how funny this is behaving on my site. I actually thought I did something wrong so I added  the same code on another page and again it pulled the footer twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118391/discussion-between-kalsowerus-and-wosley-alarico).

Comment: All right..Sent you a message there